# Eclipse content assist not working for libraries

Tags: java, eclipse, content-assist

I have following piece of code in eclipse Editor:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
public class ExampleClassTest {
...
}
```

All JARs were grouped (for PowerMock) in my own "User Library" and that library was included to the classpath
[my classpath configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tDwdJ.png)

Unfortunately the content assist for "PowerMockRunner.class" does not show any import proposal for this class
[content assists propositions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pwcnh.png)

When I am choosing "Fix project setup" I receive a proposal to add "powermock-module-junit4-1.6.4.jar" into classpath. After that the list of proposal contains positions: "Import PowerMockRunner".

Why for user libraries added to classpath content assist in eclipse not working? How to fix it?

Comment: Your setup is interesting. Why do you even define those libraries by hand as it seems you use maven?